# Is it possible to stop Windows from changing permissions on a Linux SMB share?

Tags: linux, permissions, smb

On Ubuntu I've made my user's Public folder an SMB share (using the same user as the smbuser) - I've then mapped it as a network drive on Windows XP.

I can edit, from Windows, any file on the share, but whenever I do it changes the permissions - it keeps owner permission but resets group and everyone permissions to read-only.

e.g. file is 777, I save it on the Windows side and now it's 744.

Is there anyway to stop this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to your Samba configuration.  What you want is to set the file masks, so that when Samba creates or modifies a file, the permissions are kept at a known quantity.

This is what I use in my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.  These options are set explicitly for each share:

```
[sharename]
    ...
    directory mask = 0755
    create mask = 0644
    ...
```

See the [Samba smb.conf documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for the [*create mask*](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMASK) and [*directory mask*](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#DIRECTORYMASK) options.  Use [*security mask*](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#SECURITYMASK) if you want to mask ACLs as well.

It seems that under Ubuntu, the user public folders in Ubuntu [may be controlled by the `[public]` share definition](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/unofficial_ubuntu_starter_guide/index_183.html).